# site zoom problem: not all of the components scaling as they should

Tags: css, http, xhtml

I recently develop a site and I noticed that when I use the scroll zoom(ctrl+mouse wheel) on other sites it works great but on mine it has a strange behavior with not all of the components scaling as they should.

On the css file I used only percentages in order to keep resolutions/size problem to minimum...but I don't know if that has anything to do with the present problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the width 100% on the css of the classes (for example images). This is your problem. Use width:auto; and will resize them too